# Gauss Seidel Iteration for a specific matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

We seek to solve $Au= f$ via iteration, where

$$ A =   \left ( \begin{array}{cc}
 I & S \\ -S^T & I   \end{array} \right ) $$
Where $S$ is an arbitrary square matrix in $R^n$ and $I$ is the identity matrix for $R^n$.

Now consider the relaxation scheme 
$$ A = L+D+U = 
\left ( \begin{array}{cc} Z & Z \\ -S^T & Z   \end{array} \right ) 
+\left ( \begin{array}{cc} I & Z \\ Z & I   \end{array} \right )  
+\left ( \begin{array}{cc} Z & S \\ Z & Z   \end{array} \right )  $$
  $$ (D+L)u^* = -U u_k +f $$
$$ u_{k+1}  = u_k + \omega (u^*-u_k) $$
where $Z$ is the zero matrix.

For what values $\omega$ does this scheme converge?

So far I have that 
$$ u_{k+1} = ((1-\omega)D-\omega (D+L)^{-1} U)u_k +\omega (D+L)^{-1}f$$
So if $ \Phi = ((1-\omega)D-\omega (D+L)^{-1} U)$,
we want to find $\omega$ such that $\rho (\Phi) <1$.  Some work reveals $\lambda = 1-\omega$ is an eigenvalue , thus giving us the usual restriction $0<\omega<2$.  However, I am left wondering how to solve 
$$ det( (1-\omega-\lambda)I-\omega S^TS )=0 $$

If $n = 1$ and if we let $S =s$, then

$$ \lambda = 1-\omega-\omega s^2$$

So then we require that $ 0< \omega < \frac{2}{1+s^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to solve the eigenvalue problem

$$ ((1-\omega)I-\omega S^TS) v =  \lambda  v  $$
Let's multiply by $v^T$,

$$ (1-\omega)||v||^2-\omega v^TS^TSv  =  \lambda  ||v||^2  $$

or
$$ (1-\omega)||v||^2-\omega ||Sv||^2  =  \lambda  ||v||^2  $$

If we seek $ |\lambda| < 1$, then

$$ - ||v||^2 <  (1-\omega)||v||^2-\omega ||Sv||^2  < ||v||^2  $$
or
$$ 0  <  \omega)||v||^2+\omega ||Sv||^2  < 2 ||v||^2  $$

Using $||Sv|| \leq ||S||||v||$,

$$  \omega||v||^2+\omega ||Sv||^2 \leq \omega||v||^2+\omega ||S||^2||v||^2  $$

So then this method will converge for $\omega $ such that

$$ 0 < \omega||v||^2+\omega ||S||^2||v||^2  < 2||v||^2 $$
That is,

$$ 0 < \omega  < \frac{2}{1+||S||^2} $$

This is consistent with the known solution for $n=1,S=s$.